# How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^r\leq (\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|)^r$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, inequality, polynomials

I want to establish  $\sum_{i=1}^n |a_i|^r\leq (\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|)^r$, where $a_i,r \in R$ and $|.|$ is the absolute value. Is the condition $r>0$ correct? How to prove this inequality?

Comment: If $r=0.5$ this claims that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\le \sqrt{4}$, which is false.  For a hint, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Comment: You need $r\ge1$...

Answer (score 0):

For $r\ge1$:

It's enough to do it for finite sums. The case $\sum_{j=1}^n$ follows from the case $n=2$ by induction. For $n=2$ you can assume $a_1=1$.

So you only need to show that $$(1+t)^r\ge1+t^r\quad(t\ge0).$$Let $\phi(t)=(1+t)^r-(1+t^r)$. Then $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi'(t)\ge0$ for $t\ge0$.